# Knockout containerless control flow syntax foreach misses binding update

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to use Knockout.js to build a simple CRUD table where you can list the maintenance history of a vehicle.

Everything is working except of one thing: when I POST the item over to the server and I receive a 200 OK response, I make it like in the UI you're not anymore available to fill in the inputs, but that does not work.

The item always stays in "creation mode".

[Here's a JSFiddle of the code.](http://jsfiddle.net/hszbmtxh/)

Here's where the stuff happens:

```
[...]

self.store = function () {
    if (! self.creation) return;
    console.log('stored in theory!!!!!');
    self.creation = false;
}

[...]
```

Note: All AJAX requests have been removed from the JSFiddle for demonstration / easier debugging purposes.

Comment: shouldn't creation be an observable? you have self.creation  = false; shouldn't it be self.creation = ko.observable(false); and then in the done function instead of   self.creation = false;  do self.creation(false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Every single declaration of `creation` variable needed to be transformed to a `ko.observable()`.

```
self.creation = ko.observable(false);
self.creation(false);
self.creation(true);

// instead of...

self.creation = false;
self.creation = false;
self.creation = true;
```